# How to auto align following code?

Tags: emacs

```
get_base_exp(PlayerLv)->
    case PlayerLv of
        1->30;
        2->30;
        3->60;
        4->100;
        5->160;
        6->240;
        7->330;
        8->440;
        9->570;
        10->710;
        11->880;
        12->1060
    end.
```

To the following:

```
get_base_exp(PlayerLv)->
    case PlayerLv of
        1  -> 30;
        2  -> 30;
        3  -> 60;
        4  -> 100;
        5  -> 160;
        6  -> 240;
        7  -> 330;
        8  -> 440;
        9  -> 570;
        10 -> 710;
        11 -> 880;
        12 -> 1060
    end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select the lines you want aligned
2. M-x align-regexp RET - RET
3. M-x align-regexp [0-9]+; - RET

Being a little fan of perfectly indented and aligned code, I have a keybinging for align-regexp and another for align.

Comment: It just fails for the last number of last line due to the missing final semicolon, else it is quite perfect ;^)

Comment: @Seki That final semicolon was the reason I had to use the extended form of `align-regexp` in my answer.

Comment: I should have tried before posting :-).  The regexp for properly aligning regardless lack of semicolon is "[0-9]+;?$".

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way (I have the global binding `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x \\") 'align-regexp)`):

1. Select the 12 lines you want to align
2. `C-x \` `-` `RET` to align the arrows
3. `C-x C-x` to select the region again
4. `C-u C-x \` `\(>\)` `RET` `1` `RET` `2` `RET` `n` to align the numbers after the arrows

Comment: `C-x \ -` has no effect. When `C-x \` and `-` not entered, it says `C-x \ undefined`

Comment: FYI, I'm using emacs24.3 for mac.

Comment: I am sorry, I have had the binding for `align-regexp` for such a long time I didn't realize it wasn't standard one. I updated the answer.

Comment: Great! I made some experiment with `C-u M-x align-regexp`, but did not managed to get it in one shot. In 2 passes it is ok. And I did not know the `C-x C-x` trick to reselect the region. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AlexVorobiev, thank you for the answer, but the chosed answer is clearer to me. C-x C-x is a good trick, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Mark the case expression and hit `C-u C-c C-a` (for `erlang-align-arrows`).  This gets close to what you want:

```
get_base_exp(PlayerLv) ->
    case PlayerLv of
        1  ->30;
        2  ->30;
        3  ->60;
        4  ->100;
        5  ->160;
        6  ->240;
        7  ->330;
        8  ->440;
        9  ->570;
        10 ->710;
        11 ->880;
        12 ->1060
    end.
```

You can then move to before the first score, hit `C-SPC`, move to before the last score, and hit `C-x r t` (for `string-rectangle`) and have it insert a single space in that position in every line.