# Align code in Emacs Verilog Mode?

Tags: emacs, verilog

I'm used to writing code in VHDL in emacs, which has the nice beautify functionality that will align signal assignments.  Is there something similar with the Verilog Mode?

Convert this:

```
r_Tx_Done <= 1'b1;
r_Clock_Count <= 0;
if (r_Done == 1'b1)
  begin
    r_SM_Main <= s_CLEANUP;
    o_Tx_Active <= 1'b0;
  end
```

To This:

```
r_Tx_Done     <= 1'b1;
r_Clock_Count <= 0;
if (r_Done == 1'b1)
  begin
    r_SM_Main   <= s_CLEANUP;
    o_Tx_Active <= 1'b0;
  end
```

Verilog mode does a good job keeping `if` `else` `begin` `end` aligned, but it doesn't align assignments like I want.  Note that inside the if statement doesn't align to `<=` outside the if statement.  Essentially I want each begin/end block treated separately.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an automatic alignment feature, but you can use `align-regexp` manually, as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16849125/113848).

Comment: That works for small sections of code, but for a large file that would be extremely tedious to align everything manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24472616/354577) you can try to customize `align-rules-list`.

Something like this should help:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "align"
  '(add-to-list 'align-rules-list
                '(verilog-assignment
                  (regexp . "\\(\\s-*\\)<=")
                  (mode   . '(verilog-mode))
                  (repeat . nil))))
```

Now `M-x align` should apply the new alignment rule.

Comment: I tried adding that to my .emacs file and got this message:
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/emacs/.emacs':

Symbol's value as variable is void: align-rules-list

Comment: @Russell, it sounds like you hadn't loaded `align` yet. Try the update snippet in my answer.

Comment: this solution is pretty good, but it doesn't quite behave exactly the way I would like.  If my code has nested if-else statements it pushes everything to the furthest one out, which adds quite a bit of whitespace in some situations.  I'll keep the question open for a bit longer before I accept it as an answer to see if anyone has any other suggestions.

Comment: @Russell, it might help if you add your more detailed use case to your question.

Answer (score 6):

I use verilog mode, and I have found this works by default.

1. Type `C-x h` to highlight the entire buffer.
2. Then `TAB` to get it to beautify everything. Much easier and less tedious!

Answer (score 2):

In Verilog mode for GNU Emacs 24.3.1 you can place the cursor on the non-blocking assignment operator "<=" in any of the assignment operations. For instance, in the top portion of the code:

```
r_Tx_Done <= 1'b1;
r_Clock_Count <= 0;
```

place the cursor on either of the assignment operators and type `C-c =`. The code will now become

```
r_Tx_Done     <= 1'b1;
r_Clock_Count <= 0;
```

This operation will only be performed in that section of code. This operation will not jump into any other statements: if-else, case, always, etc. In order to perform the same operation in another statement you would have to go inside that statement click on an assignment operator and type `C-c =` again.